# How to translate a connection (Step Motor Driver)?

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, driver, stepper-driver

I am following this connection to get a driver to an Arduino and a step motor. The original connection is this:

Green wire --> Step

Blue wire --> DIR

Red wire --> +5V

[image]

My driver, However, has different pins. How can I connect to my driver?

My driver:
[image]

(Note: My step motor is STEPPERONLINE Stepper Motor Nema 17 Bipolar)

Comment: You might like to search "step motor tlfong01"in this forum for newbie Q&A on basic things on step motor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check: Connect "Drive power" and turn it on. Measure the voltage between "Motor enable signal+" and "Drive power -". If you see 5V, then your inputs are not isolated from the drive supply. This is unusual and ugly, but in this case you connect:

"Step pulse signal-" -> green wire

"Direction control-" -> blue wire

Arduino GND -> "Drive power-"

"Motor enable signal-" -> "Drive power-"

Don't connect the red wire.

This non isolated context may destroy 3.3V Arduinos and you need 330 Ohm resistors in series to protect the Arduino circuits on power up.

Better option:

If you don't see a stable voltage but some floating values or zero, the inputs are isolated. This is the standard implementation of such motor drivers and good for you. These inputs allow you to connect either active high signals if you connect Input- to Arduino GND and connect Input+ to your output, or active low signals if you connect Input+ to Arduino VCC and Input- to your output.
A 3.3V Arduino may not be able to provide the needed voltage here.

Your original driver looks like active low inputs, but that's not sure.

"Motor enable signal+" -> Arduino VCC or new control port if you like

"Motor enable signal-" -> Arduino GND

"Step pulse signal+" -> Arduino VCC

"Step pulse signal-" -> green wire

"Direction control+" -> Arduino VCC

"Direction control-" -> blue wire

The active high version would be:

"Motor enable signal+" -> Arduino VCC or new control port if you like

"Motor enable signal-" -> Arduino GND

"Step pulse signal+" -> green wire

"Step pulse signal-" -> Arduino GND

"Direction control+" -> blue wire

"Direction control-" -> Arduino GND

You can try both, it won't destroy anything